# Extract text of node, ignoring childNodes

Tags: javascript

Given a simple structure like this:

```
<td><span>Text1</span></td>
<td><span>Text2</span></td>
<td><span>Text3</span></td>
<td><span><a href='#'>Link</a>Text4</span></td>
```

I am trying to extract all Text1-4 with Javascript, w/out any child nodes.

#### Loop for the cols

```
...
x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
...
```

#### Output for each x

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
<a href='#'>Link</a>Text4
```

Is there a simple way to "ignore" the html tags of an element?

#### Edit

I tried this

```
if(x.hasChildNodes()){
    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
}
```

but that gives me `Link` obviously

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.innerText` which will get text and all nested text for you, and replace `div` with `td` for your example, I just added it to show result

```js
const tags = document.querySelectorAll('div > span');

tags.forEach(tag => {
    const nodes = tag.childNodes;
    nodes.forEach(node => {
     if(node.nodeType === node.TEXT_NODE) { 
        console.log(node.nodeValue);
     }
    });
});
```

```html
<div><span>Text1</span></div>
<div><span>Text2</span></div>
<div><span>Text3</span></div>
<div><span><a href='#'>Link</a>Text4</span></div>
```

Comment: But for the last one it gives me `LinkText4`, I actually only want `Text4`

Comment: @PrimuS ah I thought you need nested text too, I have updated my answer please check again